Let $X \sim T_n$. Prove that $E(X)=0, \ n>1.$
I'm studying Probability and we were on the topic of random variables and their respective expected values. My professor asked us to prove that if $X \sim T_n$, where $T_n$ is a Student T distribution with n degrees of freedom, then, $E(X)=0, \ n>1.$
However, I'm not sure if this is the correct way of handling the integral. I noticed that when I tried to change variables I made mistakes and that made doubt myself when I tried to do it without changing variables.
Let $X \sim T_n$.
We want to prove that $E(X)=0, \ n>1.$ Thus, we have that
$$E(X) \stackrel {def}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}} xf_X(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x \cdot \frac{1}{B(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})}n^{-\frac{1}{2}} \bigg(1+\frac{x^2}{n} \bigg)^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}dx=$$
$$=\frac{n^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{B(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x \bigg (\frac{n+x^2}{n} \bigg)^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} dx= \frac{n^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{n^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}B(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x ({n+x^2})^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} dx=$$
$$=\frac{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}{2B(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} ({n+x^2})^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} 2xdx.$$
Note that
$$(n+x^2)^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}2x=\frac{d}{dx} \bigg[\frac{(n+x^2)^{\frac{1-n}{2}}}{\frac{1-n}{2}} \bigg].$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}{2B(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} ({n+x^2})^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} 2xdx = \frac{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}{2B(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \bigg[\frac{(n+x^2)^{\frac{1-n}{2}}}{\frac{1-n}{2}} \bigg]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=$$
$$=\frac{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(1-n)B(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \big[(n+x^2)^{\frac{1-n}{2}} \big]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}, \ n>1.$$
Given that $n>1$, we get that $\frac{1-n}{2}<0.$ Consequently,
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} (n+x^2)= +\infty \Longrightarrow \lim_{x \to+\infty} (n+x^2)^{\frac{1-n}{2}}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} (n+x^2)= +\infty \Longrightarrow \lim_{x \to -\infty} (n+x^2)^{\frac{1-n}{2}}=0.$$
Then, we can conclude that
$$\frac{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(1-n)B(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \big[(n+x^2)^{\frac{1-n}{2}} \big]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=0, \ n>1.$$
$\therefore E(X)=0, \ n>1.$

The density is an even function, so if expectation exists, it is zero. For $n>1$, the expectation exists because the density is a continuous function decaying like $|x|^{-n-1}$ at $\pm \infty$.

You can check that $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution (i.e. $X$ is symmetric about $0$). So if $E(X)$ exists, you must have $E(X)=E(-X)=-E(X)$, implying $E(X)=0$.

I'll verify your approach in a different manner.
Recall that the probability density function of a student's t-distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom is
$$f_X(x)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{n\pi} \ \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}, \ \ x∈ℝ$$
Observe that this is an even function as it depends on $x^2$. Hence, $$f_X(-x)=f_X(x)$$Thus the expected value of $X$ is $$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x)dx$$Since $x$ is an odd function and $f_X(x)$ is even, their product $xf_X(x)$ is an odd function;
$$xf_X(x)=-xf_X(-x)$$Recalling that the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval $[-a,a]$ is zero (provided the integral converges),
$$\int_{-a}^{a}(\text{odd function})dx=0$$For large $x$, $$f_X(x)\approx Cx^{-(n+1)}$$ $$xf_X(x)\approx Cx^{-n}$$
The integral $\int_M^{\infty}x^{-n}dx$ converges if $n>1$. And since $xf_X(x)$ is integrable over $ℝ$ for $n>1$, it is an odd function over a symmetric inverval. Hence we now have $$\boxed{E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x)dx=0}$$
We now have $E(X)=0$ when $n>1$. Your working out is indeed correct.
